# Visual Studio Code Not Retrieving Full LWC Package

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

**tl;dr** - how to make sure `Retrieve Source from Org` includes XML file

**Description**

Normally when I retrieve source data for an LWC from an org in vs code the resulting file looks like this:

[image]

For some reason now when I retrieve them it looks like this:

[image]

The HTML and JavaScript files are in their own separate files, and the `js-meta.xml` file is missing.

Furthermore, when I make changes to the HTML or JavaScript file and attempt to run the `SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org` command, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1616179398177\lwc\adminControlPanel\adminControlPanel.html'
```

As a result I am unable to work on LWC files at this time.

**Question**
How to make sure `Retrieve Source from Org` for LWC files includes the XML file?

**Attempted Fixes**

- Restart Visual Studio Code
- Uninstall and reinstall Salesforce Extension Pack
- Reauthorize org
- Update Visual Studio Code
- Reinstall SFDX
- Start a new project with manifest

I have also searched online for this error via github tickets, stack exchange, and other sites, but have not found a solution.

Comment: First question: why are the adminControlPanel JS and HTML files in directories of the same name?! Something went horribly wrong when VSCode retrieved this LWC in the first place...

Comment: No idea, and agreed - something was seriously broken

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know exactly what the solution was, completing the following steps (in this order) seems to have resolved the issues:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the Salesforce CLI
2. Uninstall and reinstall VisualForce
3. Uninstall and reinstall the Salesforce Extension Pack
4. Start a new project
5. Log out of all authorized orgs and re-log into the org

I suspect that #5 may have been the key, but I wasn't able to isolate it in the process and can't confirm for sure.

I'm not going to mark this as "the solution" because I don't know exactly what did it, but hopefully this is helpful to anyone encountering this problem in the future.